# Using CNN for data that has not shape NxM

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to use a CNN for a game, which has a 3x3 board. As additional input factor I want to use a value that represents the turn of the player, so +1 for player A and -1 for player B. Is there a way to add that additional information to a CNN?

Comment: Its almost impossible to answer this question without a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I'm sorry but for someone who can actually help me, my post contains all the relevant information. I want to pass a board position with size 3x3 plus an extra dimension to a CNN. So basically a tensor with size 10.

Comment: We're probably going to need more information than this. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra row to make the input shape `4x3` and add the value of the player detail as the last cell and leaving the other two as null:

```
* * * 
* * *
* * *
. . x
```

The `*`s denote the original matrix, `.` denote a `null` value , ie, `0`. And `x` can be your `+1` or `-1` value.

Comment: Thank you!!! I receive much better results now :)